# sql - Why a query with fewer rows to scan (according to explain) actually runs significantly slower than one with much more rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

**TL;DR**

When querying the same table, why would the first query below (scans 20 rows) take significantly longer time than the second (scans 35k+ rows)?

First query:

```
id  select_type     table       type         possible_keys     key                            key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          Groups      range        <lots of keys>    group_name_ip_address_idx      317         NULL    20      Using index condition; Using where
```

Second query:

```
id  select_type     table       type         possible_keys     key                    key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          Groups      ref_or_null  <lots of keys>    email_address_idx      768         const   35415   Using index condition; Using where
```

I'm using the "rows" in explain as a direct indicator of the performance of the query (which might be wrong?), but still the 20 rows query takes much longer time than the 35k query confuses me. Not an sql expert, can someone educate me what could possibly cause that?

**Longer version:**

I have a table "Groups" that has a field "group_name" and 20 more fields ("field_1", "field_2", ..., "field_20") about customer information.

I'm using this table to determine, when I see a customer's information, which group(s) it matches to. For a dummy example, if the table has a record where group name is "US male" and the 20 fields are all null except for "citizenship" is "US" and "gender" is "male", then it means whenever I see a customer with citizenship "US" and gender "male", he matches the group "US male".

I'm using this query (Query1) which takes 3~5ms to achieve this goal:

```
select * from Groups 
where group_name = "US male" 
  and (field_1 = "something1" or field_1 is null) 
  and (field_2 = "something2" or field_2 is null) 
  and ... and (field_20 = "something20" or field_20 is null)
```

Those "something"s represent the information of the current customer that I want to know which groups he/she matches. So if this query returns anything, it means a match; otherwise not a match.

explain outputs of above query:

```
id  select_type     table       type         possible_keys     key                               key_len     ref           rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          Groups      ref_or_null  <lots of keys>    group_name_email_address_idx      962         const,const   2       Using index condition; Using where
```

Note that one customer could match multiple groups, so for N group name I'll need N queries like the above. Now with N getting bigger, I want to use one single query instead of N small queries to do the same thing, and this is where I got stuck.

I first tried removing the `group_name = "XXXX"` condition in `where` - select all matched groups instead of checking one by one (Query2).

```
select * from Groups 
where (field_1 = "something1" or field_1 is null) 
  and (field_2 = "something2" or field_2 is null) 
  and ... and (field_20 = "something20" or field_20 is null)
```

explain outputs:

```
id  select_type     table       type         possible_keys     key                    key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          Groups      ref_or_null  <lots of keys>    email_address_idx      768         const   35415   Using index condition; Using where
```

This is slow (~70ms) because it's not able to use any indexes that need group name, which are the most efficient ones because group_name has lowest cardinality. (number of rows needed for scanning is 35k compared to 2 in the first query). So this didn't work out very well.

Then in order for the query to use group name indexes I added `group_name in (<all group names>)` in `where` (Query3):

```
select * from Groups 
where group_name in ("group1", "group2", ..., "groupN") 
  and (field_1 = "something1" or field_1 is null) 
  and (field_2 = "something2" or field_2 is null) 
  and ... and (field_20 = "something20" or field_20 is null)
```

explain outputs:

```
id  select_type     table       type         possible_keys     key                            key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          Groups      range        <lots of keys>    group_name_ip_address_idx      317         NULL    20      Using index condition; Using where
```

I saw the rows it needs to scan is 20, which is significantly better than 35415 so I was expecting it to run fast. However when I tried running it, it actually takes much more time than Query2 (about 20x) which broke my service.

After all these, I'm very confused now why would a query that scans 20 rows take much longer time than one that scans 35k rows? Am I reading the explain outputs wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? sql server <> mysql

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and edit to MySQL because SQL Server has no "Explain".

Comment: An `in` in SQL is the equivalent of a bunch or `or`s, and an `or` is resolved as, essentially, running each operand as a separate query, then returning the union of the result sets. Practically speaking, you need to come up with a way to restrict the length of the `in` clause.

Comment: Thanks for editing and the corrections. @tpdi "An in in SQL is the equivalent of a bunch or ors, and an or is resolved as, essentially, running each operand as a separate query, then returning the union of the result sets" so my expectation was that the `in` query takes at most 10x times of one single small query (Query 1 in the question), but in fact it takes seconds. Do you know why would that be?

Comment: All of those result sets have to be unioned (combined, with duplicates removed, probably by sorting but possibly by hashing). This means either allocating memory, or to save memory, swapping to disk. How big is your union?

Comment: @tpdi each result set should only have a few rows by design, for N=10 I'd expect the union to be of the size ~30 at the most.